# FullCalendar 5 - How to add Font Awesome icons to an Event title

Tags: css, fullcalendar, font-awesome-5, fullcalendar-5

I am trying to add Font Awesome icons to an Event in FullCalendar 5. I have tried using css:

```
<script>
     window.FontAwesomeConfig = {
        searchPseudoElements: true
    }
</script>
```

I found the above while searching for answers and os placed before the

```
<style type="text/css">
```

The css:

```
.cssItalic {
    font-family: "Font Awesome\ 5 Free" !important;
    content: "\f55e" !important;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    text-decoration-thickness: 5px !important;
    text-decoration-color: white !important;
}
```

This does not add the icon; however, the rest works (e.g., italicised, bolded, underlined). I Have also tried font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free" !important; and font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Pro" !important;.

I have also tried eventDidMount:

```
eventDidMount: function(event, element) {
    element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-bus-alt'></i>");
},
```

However, I get a console error on the element. Note: I can not get eventRender to work in FullCalendar 5.

I have been working on this and I think I may be a bit closer with:

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {
    console.log(info.event.title);
    ("info.event.title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-bus-alt'></i>");
},
```

The console.log displays the first title. However, I then get a console log error of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: "info.event.title".append is not a function
```

I have also tried without the quotes (same error):

```
(info.event.title).prepend("<i class='fa fa-bus-alt'></i>");
```

Ben Souchet has come up with these solutions:

```
eventDidMount: function(event, element) {
    element.find(".fc-title").prepend("<i class='fa fa-bus-alt'></i>");
},
```

This displays the tag (i.e., not the icon) at the start (i.e., before the time):

```
<i class='fa fa-bus-alt'></i>
```

Ben also provided:

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {
    console.log(info.event.title);
    $(info.el + ' .fc-event-title').prepend("<i class='fa fa-bus-alt'></i>");
},
```

This solution displays  a different number of multiple icons between the time and title in month, week and day view (see attached images) and an error in list view. The error is:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [object HTMLTableRowElement].fc-event-title
```

[image: Month view]

[image: Week view]

[image: Day view]

Based on Ben Souchet's answer I can up with:

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {
    console.log(info.event.title);
    $(info.el).find('.fc-event-title').prepend("<i class='fa fa-bus-alt' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Test'></i>");
},
```

And my final answer reading in the icon from server side is:

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {
    var icon = info.event.extendedProps.icon;
    if (info.event.extendedProps.icon) {
        $(info.el).find('.fc-event-title').prepend("<i class='fa fa-"+icon+"' data-toggle='tooltip' title='Test'></i>");
    }
},
```

Comment: I just updated my answer, take a look :)

Comment: Very happy you find a working solution, I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no experience with `fullcalendar` but I think you are very close with the `eventDidMount`.

**Updated answer**:

```js
eventDidMount: function(event, element) {
  // Create the icon
  let icon = document.createElement("i");
  icon.classList.add('fa', 'fa-bus-alt');
  // Add icon before the title
  element.querySelector(".fc-title").prepend(icon);
},
```

See also the last section of **@Glyn** post to see what he ended up using to display the icon :)

**Previous answer**:

```js
eventDidMount: function(info) {
    console.log(info.event.title);
    info.el.prepend("<i class='fa fa-bus-alt'></i>");
},
```

In the documentation it's indicated that `el` is the DOM element so in your case you need to `prepand` to this element.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you so much for your help. I have tried so many different solutions and searched for a solution. It seems that my inexperience is the key as I have seen ".el" and not understood what I was reading. Anyway, this now displays the icon; however, not properly. I will give a full explanation by editing my original question, so please look there.

Comment: Hi Ben, I did it slightly differently (please see my edit). I will also try your way. Thank you so much!

Comment: Seems to me there is something wrong or outdated on the accepted answer. Testing thins on my side, the `eventDidMount` callback function has only one parameter, not two.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax results :

```
events = [{
    'title': '%icon% My Super Title',
    'icon': '<i class="fa fa-bus-alt"></i>',
    ...
  }, {
    ...
  }
];
```

for eventDidMount :

```
new FullCalendar.Calendar(..., {
  ...
  eventDidMount: (info) => {
    info.el.querySelector('fc-event-title').innerHTML(
      info.event.title.replace('%icon%', info.event.extendedProps.icon)
    );
  },
  ...
});
```