# Best approach to add a font-awesome icon to the time column of an event on fullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, font-awesome

Current state:

[image]

What I want to achieve:

[image]

So, I have a fullcalendar v6, and in the `.fc-event-time` I want to append a Font Awesome icon, as described in the pictures.

I have already explored things a bit using

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {

},
```

Tried also to respond to the `eventContent` hook, but didn't achieve what I wanted.

Does anyone have any idea how to do it? Note: jQuery is available here.

#### UPDATE:

I could reach to the `fc-event-time` element, using the following code:

```
    eventDidMount: function (info) {
        info.el.getElementsByClassName("fc-event-time")[0].innerHTML += '<br /><i class="fas fa-stamp"></i>';
    },
```

, but now the output is weird:

[image]

and in the week view:

[image]

Comment: a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70546529/fullcalendar-5-how-to-add-font-awesome-icons-to-an-event-title

Comment: @MicheleDeFalco: I had already spotted such question before. The poster wants to handle the event TITLE element, not the event TIME element.

Comment: @MicheleDeFalco: I finally got to achieve the effect I wanted, looking to that answer again. I will post it as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the effect I wanted, looking to the [FullCalendar 5 - How to add Font Awesome icons to an Event title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70546529/fullcalendar-5-how-to-add-font-awesome-icons-to-an-event-title) question's source code.

```
    eventDidMount: function (info) {
        $(info.el).find(".fc-event-time").append('<br />&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-stamp"></i>');
    },
```

Thank you, @MicheleDeFalco for making me to look again to the question you linked on your comment!

[image]